# How to utilize scalar multiplication in einsum?

Tags: python, numpy

In https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html
it is mentioned that

> Broadcasting and scalar multiplication:
> np.einsum('..., ...', 3, c) array([[ 0,  3,  6],[ 9, 12, 15]])

it seems einsum can mimick prefactors alpha/beta in DGEMM
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html

Does it imply that it (include scalar multiplication inside einsum as one step) will be faster than two steps: (1) `A,B->C` and (2) `C*prefactor`?

I tried to extend https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/ as

```
    import numpy as np
    A = np.array([0, 1, 2])
    B = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],  [ 4,  5,  6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
    C = np.einsum('i,ij->i', 2., A, B)
    print(C)
```

and got `ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand`.

So, my question is, is there any method to include scalar factor inside einsum and accelerate the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this `scalar` feature, but here's how it works:

```
In [422]: np.einsum('i,ij->i',A,B)
Out[422]: array([ 0, 22, 76])

In [423]: np.einsum(',i,ij->i',2,A,B)
Out[423]: array([  0,  44, 152])
```

The time savings appears to be minor

```
In [424]: timeit np.einsum(',i,ij->i',2,A,B)
11.5 µs ± 271 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [425]: timeit 2*np.einsum('i,ij->i',A,B)
12.3 µs ± 274 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

another example:

```
In [427]: np.einsum(',i,,ij->i',3,A,2,B)
Out[427]: array([  0, 132, 456])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry how to use timeit? `import timeit   print(timeit.timeit(np.einsum('i,ij->i', A, B)))` leads to `ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable`

Comment: @Geositta Just wrap your code in quotes.

Comment: @Thyebri, thanks. I got `timeit np.einsum(',i,ij->i',2,A,B)  SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `timeit.timeit("np.einsum('i,ij->i', A, B)")`

Comment: `NameError: name 'np' is not defined` ...

Comment: Sorry, my examples from a `IPython` session with common `import numpy as np`.  `timeit` and `%%timeit` are timing 'magics' provided by `IPython`.  I keep such a session running when answering questions like this.  Lots of others use a similar setup.  The `In/Out` line labels are also characteristic of `IPython`.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you one more time, does the scalar in einsum work as replacing the alpha/beta coefficient in DGEMM or similar functions in BLAS? I found `%timeit np.einsum('i,ij->i', A, B) 4.37 µs ± 177 ns per loop` and `%timeit np.einsum(',i,ij->i', 2, A, B) 5.76 µs ± 449 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. If I change alpha/beta coefficient in DGEMM using Fortran (in another contraction, not this one), the time difference is negligible (<1%) Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation details.